# Как настроить коллбеки для Яндекс Кассы в php-окружении?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, яндекс-касса

Есть ли какой-либо мануал более вменяемый чем официальная документация?

Дело в том что в документации указаны для настройки два url - `checkUrl` и `avisoUrl`, а в настройках моего магазина на Яндексе - лишь ОДИН url - URL для уведомлений.

Разрабатываю оплату через перенаправление на сайт Яндекс.Кассы.
Мне нужно всего лишь получить ответ о том что оплата прошла и изменить статус заказа у себя в магазине по коллбеку.

И ещё - как защититься от хакерских атак по данному URL?

Comment: Так написали якобы все в курсе о какой доке речь и что за либы используете.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/shop-config/intro-docpage/ - это то что в документации, https://imgur.com/a/djEGGPA - это то что у меня

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v54xwq5 - ещё